# Iterating hashmap, using keyset/entryset

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap

I'm trying to access the stuff I put in my hashmap, but it's not working.
Apparently the iterator for hashmap doesnt have anything. It cant do a mapIter.hasNext(), it'll be false.

Here's the code:

```
    Iterator<Product> cIter = getCartContent(cart).iterator();
    HashMap<Product, Integer> hash = new HashMap<Product, Integer>();
    Iterator<Product> mIter = hash.keySet().iterator();

    Product p;

    while(cIter.hasNext()) {
        p = cIter.next();

        if(hash.containsKey(p))
            hash.put(p, hash.get(p) + 1);
        else
            hash.put(p, 1);

    }

    if(!mIter.hasNext())
        System.out.println("Empty mIter");
```

Comment: Show us the bigger picture then. Prove to us that there are elements in it. Post an SSCCE.

Comment: Using hashmap.isEmpty() return false. Sorry, I'm new at this..

Comment: There are a ton of variables in your code you don't show us being created, nor is it commented to explain them. For example, what is `getCartContent`? Are you sure the problem isn't in that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call

```
HashMap<Product, Integer> hashmap = new HashMap<Product, Integer>();
Iterator<Product> mapIter = hashmap.keySet().iterator();
```

The `Iterator` that is created has a view of the empty `HashMap`, because you have yet to add anything to it. When you call `hasNext()`, even if the `HashMap` itself contains elements, the `Iterator`'s view doesn't see it.

Create the `Iterator` when you absolutely need it, not before, ie. right before you call `hasNext()` in your code.

```
Iterator<Product> mapIter = hashmap.keySet().iterator();

if(!mapIter.hasNext())
    System.out.println("Empty mapIter");
```

Comment: Oh, you beat me to it!

Comment: @Codebox You're welcome. It's not necessarily a facepalm. Some `Iterator` implementations might be different.